# Building a hash in RoR: use object reference or ID as key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, memory, hash

I am wondering what is the best way to build a custom hash in terms of choosing a proper key. Options available are:

```
my_hash = {}
for user in User.all do
  my_hash[user] = some_value    # option 1 using object reference
  my_hash[user.id] = some_value # option 2 using object id
end
```

I think option 2 should be the way to go as it consumes less memory and might be faster. However, it does have a downside:

Option 1 would allow me to pass the hash to the view and just do

```
<% @my_hash.collect do |user, value| %>
  <p><%= user.name %> | <%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

whereas option 2 requires some way to get the user from the id in the key.

Any recommendation how to deal with this is greatly appreciated. **If you are in favor of option 2, please indicate how to best access the object referenced by the id in the hash key**. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true question is "how are you going to use this hash". If you need to iterate and show some information about the users, the first option is better ; if you need to access a value corresponding to a user's ID, option 2 is better. You could even think of another solution

```
my_hash = {}

User.all.each do |u|
  my_hash[u.id] = [u, some_value]
end
```

My point is : there is no correct answer, it really depends on the use you're going to make of this hash.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that 3rd option out, @thoferon. Actually I'm doing it on a case to case basis right now, but wanted to refactor my code to stick to one of the two alternatives. The reason is that I always end up wondering whether the key is ID or obj. reference. I like your solution because it allows both handling all data in the hash and retreiving single entries very easily. Will accept the answer after some time, if no better solution comes up. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 should not be any slower b/c object reference is not actually different from an Integer in terms of required memory storage.

You can make your own tests for example assigning 100000 or 1000000 values to hash, one time with integers, and other with objects.

I'm sure you will have different results, depending on your OS, x86 or x64, and ruby version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Haven't done any performance benchmarks, yet, so I need to get familiar with them first. I see one issue with option one though: When I want to get a specific entry, e.g. @my_hash[User.first], then 1) I have the user in memory twice; 2) ruby/rails would compare the primary keys of the objects to find the correct entry in the hash. Would option 1 then still be the recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord defines `ActiveRecord::Base#hash` as `id.hash`, so there is absolutely no difference whether you use `user` or `user.id` as a hash key. Having said that option 1 is obviously better in your particular case.